# Which Version of SP designer should I use for SPO?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, version

I would like to ask which version of SP designer should I use if I am using SharePoint Online Classic Experience?

I check the SP version through [HERE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Which-version-of-SharePoint-am-I-using-3575ff57-037f-48cf-9398-99080c34b25f). Not 100% sure that I right but please correct me if the version is not SPO Classic Experience. This is the screenshot of the SPO I'm using now.

[image: SP Version]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On 20 January 2016,  Microsoft announced the availability of SharePoint Server 2016 Release Candidate (RC), **but it was not included** InfoPath 2016 and SharePoint Designer 2016 as SharePoint Server 2013 RC!

So the **SharePoint Designer 2013** will still be used, against

- SharePoint Server 2013.
- SharePoint Server 2016.
- SharePoint Online.

> **Note:** The support for InfoPath 2013 and SharePoint Designer 2013 will match the support lifecycle for SharePoint Server 2016, running
>   until **2026**.

For more details check [SharePoint designer 2016 and InfoPath 2016 in SharePoint server 2016, what’re the alternatives?](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/05/06/did-you-consider-powerapps-is-a-replacement-for-sharepoint-designer-and-infopath-in-sharepoint/)